# fb.login does not ask email permission

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I just called the below codes in my webpage.

```
FB.init({
appId  : 'XXXXXX',
status : true, 
cookie : true, 
oauth: true,
xfbml  : true  
});

FB.login(function(response) {
// handle the response
}, {scope: 'email'});
```

It does not ask permission. Please advice me.

Comment: Does the login window show at all?

Comment: yes, I got the login popup

Comment: Have you maybe given email permission to that app before? Try removing it completely from the app settings under your Facebook account, and then try again.

Comment: Ok CBroe. Thanks for your reply. But It partially works..